# Display message to user that a file cannot be loaded to program c#

Tags: c#, io, messagebox, streamreader, windows

I am new to working with System.IO.

I have an application that grabs a Json file from the web and only grabs partial data to display on the Windows Application Form's controls.
The form allows the user to save the data as a new file and load a file if ONLY it contains the "indicator" I added in when the file was saved that tells the program it was saved by my program.

Everything works.

Whenever a file that doesn't contain that indicator is loaded to the program, it doesn't show nothing which is what I want it to do, but I also want a Messagebox.Show() to pop up and let the user know why the values are empty and why nothing happened.

```
if(openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string dataLine = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFile.FileName)))
    {

        dataLine = read.ReadToEnd();
        string[] beginningOfData = dataLine.Split(',');
        string temporary = string.Empty;
        foreach (string line in beginningOfData)
        {
             //Indicator
             if(line.Contains("Indicator")
             {
                temporary = line.substring(9);
                //Goes through the rest of the file
                //Converts data to control value and adds it
             }
             else
             {
                //Where I tried to display the message box       
             }
        }
    }

}
```

This what I've tried, but it wasn't working as I wanted it too

```
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("Can't load data.");      
}
```

It would still show the MessageBox even if it read that the indicator was there and displayed the data inside the corresponding controls. Also whenever I tried to close the MessageBox it would just show it again.

So I decided to this instead:

```
else if(!line.contains("Indicator"))
{ 
    MessageBox.Show("Can't load data.");
    break;
}
```

and in this way too:

```
else
{
    if(!line.contains("Indicator")) 
    { 
        MessageBox.Show("Can't load data.");
        break;
    }
}
```

I also tried making it more specific by doing

```
if(line.contains("Indicator") == false)
{
   //Code here
}
```

But it would still display it even if the file was created by the program.

The break; did stop the message box from re-appearing again, but I only want the MessageBox to show when it's the incorrect text file (not containing the indicator) and allow me to close the MessageBox to try again.

Comment: Do you want the file to contain a line where you have the value `Indicator` or do you want just a single `Indicator` value across all the lines from the file?

Comment: The first one. 

When I open up the text file that was created it's displayed like:
(just an example)
Indicator, Data:1, Data2:word,

Comment: Is this considered a valid file:

Line1 : "someText"
Line2 : "Indicator"
...

Comment: No, I hardcoded the "Indicator" at the beginning of each new file that is being saved.

Comment: Similar to this: 
"Indicator" + "," + "Data:" + control.value + "," + "Data:" + control.value + "," and so on.  It's just a string of data, but it always has the "Indicator" in the beginning

Comment: Take a look at [my](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44597315/5687778) answer does that do the job?

Comment: Why not deserialize the json data in the file to an object that is more clearly defined? Then you won't have to do string manipulation on it / it should be more robust.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did this instead and it worked for my application

```
if(openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
    string dataLine = string.Empty;
    using (StreamReader read = new StreamReader(File.OpenRead(openFile.FileName)))
    {
        //Changed happened here

        dataLine = read.ReadToEnd();
        string[] beginningOfData = dataLine.Split(',');
        string temporary = string.Empty;

        if(beginningOfData.Contains("Indicator"))
        {   
           temporary = dataLine.Substring(9);
           foreach(string realData in beginningOfData)
           {
             //Goes through file
           }
        }
        else
        {
          MessageBox.Show("Can't load data");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That's what I was asking in my comments under your question. Guess I didn't understood what you meant, I got the impression that this code wont work as not every line necessarily contains "Indicator", this requires just a single line to contain it :).

Answer (score 2):

You can wrap the `foreach` into an if statement which will use some LINQ code to determine if all lines contain "indicator":

```
if (beginningOfData.All(line => line.ToLower().Contains("indicator")))
{
    string temporary = string.Empty;
    foreach (string line in beginningOfData)
    {
        temporary = line.Substring(9);
        //Goes through the rest of the file
        //Converts data to control value and adds it
    }
}
else
{
    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Can't load data.");   
}
```

Comment: Is the line inside line => line a new variable being declared? Otherwise I don't understand where it's coming from.

Comment: @BeginnerCoder this is called lambda expression, It internally operates with a `foreach` loop, so this is basically the `line` here `foreach(var line in lines)`. I can include a foreach example just to illustrate how it works.

Comment: I sort of followed what you were trying to do, but without using lambda and got it work. Thanks for the lightbulb moment!

Answer (score 0):

`Contains` is case-sensitive.  Try this for your evaluation:

```
line.IndexOf("Indicator", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0
```